# How would I convert ISO 8601 durations into a seconds or milliseconds in Lua?

Tags: lua, iso8601

I need to implement a lua function to convert the time format in `ISO 8601` to seconds or milliseconds, is there any built-in libraries available in `Lua` or we have to implement?
Examples for ISO 8601 format :

```
PT1S, PT0.010S, PT0.001S---> to seconds or milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below converts strings of the form `PTxxxS`:

```
s="PT0.001S"
print(tonumber(s:match("PT([%d.]+)S")))
```

More generally, this code parses a duration string into a table, which you can then process easily:

```
s= "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" 
t = {Y=0, M=0, W=0, D=0, H=0, M=0, S=0}
for v,k in s:gmatch("([%d.,]+)(%u)") do
    t[k]=tonumber(v)
end
```

Comment: does anyone help converting seconds to is08601 format? ex: 70 secs --> PT1M10S

Comment: @sam, ask a separate question