# LUA: Simpler string pattern solution

Tags: string, design-patterns, lua

I'm studying LUA on my own and would like a little help on this next piece of code:

```
offset= "1h2m3s4f"

off_h = offset:match("(%d+)h")
off_m = offset:match("(%d+)m")
off_s = offset:match("(%d+)s")
off_f = offset:match("(%d+)f")

print(off_h)
print(off_m)
print(off_s)
print(off_f)
```

I've tried everything to concat the pattern into a single line offset:match but after reading many ressources online I am still clueless how to do it.
The problem is, the user might enter only 2m3s4f without any numbers for h or
he might enter only 1m2f.

My tests on a single pattern check were resulting in full nil values when I removed one of the pattern condition. I tried adding the magic char ? to the different patterns but that didn't do the trick.
Any pointer would be appreciated!
Thanks,

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48522847/107090

Answer (score 2):

```
for _, offset in ipairs{"1h2m3s4f", "2m3s4f", "1m2f"} do
   local fields = {}
   offset:gsub("(%d+)([hmsf])", function(n,u) fields[u] = n end)
   print(fields.h, fields.m, fields.s, fields.f)
end
```

Output:

```
1    2    3    4
nil  2    3    4
nil  1    nil  2
```

---

```
-- Shortest, but slowest variant
for _, offset in ipairs{"1h2m3s4f", "2m3s4f", "1m2f"} do
   local h, m, s, f = offset:match"^(%d-)h?(%d-)m?(%d-)s?(%d-)f?$"
   print(h, m, s, f)
end
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  4
   2  3  4
   1     2
```

Comment: Any reason for doing the `reverse` in first approach? I mean is it faster?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question was, how is that any different from `"^(%d-)h?(%d-)m?(%d-)s?(%d-)f?$"` pattern match? And since there are no `reverse` involved; wouldn't it be faster?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Yes, reverse()-version is not any better than the last variant.  Removed it.

Comment: Huge thanks guys! 
I'll study both answers posted to increase my LUA knowledge. Thanks a bunch for the answers!!